# Is there an undecidable decision problem that computable algorithm for it leads to an algorithm for halting problem?

Tags: computability, undecidability, halting-problem

Suppose, to the contrary, that there exists a computable algorithm for some undecidable decision problem. Would this mean that halting problem would be solved by a computable algorithm? I know that the converse is true for a decision problem in RE complexity class, but not for the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Let me rephrase your question. Suppose $O$ is undecidable; can Turing machines with an $O$-oracle solve the halting problem? There are some undecidable $O$ for which this is false. Constructing such $O$ is known as *Post's problem*, solved using the *priority method*; [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree#Post.27s_problem_and_the_priority_method) has some details.